# Index Match using ranges - Compile Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets of data. I have a list of values in sheet "BSP" and I am trying to run a script that will look and return any of those values that occur in a range in sheet "Invoice".

I basically want to know which BSP values hit in the Invoice worksheet.  However, the values in the Invoice worksheet are not always in one specific column. Is there a way to have excel search either a range of 4 or 5 columns, or the whole sheet and return a list of the matches?

I have the code below that I was attempting to write. I am getting a 'Compile Error' - Expected End of Statement.

**test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index("Invoice").Range("H10:P30000"). Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(0, Sheets("BSP").Range("A2:A5500"), 0) 1)**

If anyone would be so kind as to advise what is causing this error or this portion of code, or if my goal is even possible, it would be tremendously appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Small corrections:

```
test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Invoice").Range("H10:P30000"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(0, Sheets("BSP").Range("A2:A5500"), 0) 1)
```